# WPF MVVM - How to create a Hierarchial Datagrid with a column that contains a dynamically-selected control type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following ViewModel:

```cs
// Top-level Policy ViewModel
class MainWindowVM {
    // A collection of ViewModels, each mapping to an application role.
    public List<RolePolicyVM> ComponentPolicyVMs { get; set; } = new();
}

// Contains the component policies pretaining to a specific application roles.
class RolePolicyVM {
    // Role name
    public String Name { get; set; }
    
    // Component policies applying to the ADCS role.
    public List<ComponentPolicyVM> ComponentPolicies { get; set; } = new();
}

// Contains the component policies pretaining to a specific agent plugin or worker
class ComponentPolicyVM {
    // Plugin or worker Id. Not rendered.
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    // The description of the setting to be displayed in the AgentConfig tool
    public String Description { get; set; }
    
    // The tooltip to be displayed when mousing over the Description TextBlock
    public String ToolTipText { get; set; }
    
    // The value to bind to a control
    public Object Value { get; set; }
    
    // The data type of "Value". 
    // This property determines what type of control to render.
    public Type ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a DataGrid or TreeView control which is dynamically populated based on the elements in `AppPolicyVM.ComponentPolicyVMs`.

- The top-level hierarchy is bound to `RolePolicyVM.Name`
- The second-level must contain 2 columns:

  - The first column is bound to `ComponentPolicyVM.Description`
  - The second column is bound to `ComponentPolicyVM.Value`, but here is where it gets tricky: I need the control which is rendered here to be dynamic based on the value of `ComponentPolicyVM.ValueType`. So for instance, if it's `typeof(string)` we see a TextBox. If it's `typeof(bool)` it's a checkbox. I need to support `bool`, `string` and `int`.

I've gotten as far as to render a `TreeView` which always renders a checkbox:
[image]

What I'm stuck on (and not sure if this is even possible) is how to add logic which can dynamically render the proper type of control based on `ComponentPolicyVM.ValueType`.

Here's the XAML I have so far:

```xml
<Window x:Class="AppPolicyConfig.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AppPolicyConfig.ViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppPolicyConfig"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="10"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentPolicyVMs}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentPolicies}" DataType="{x:Type vm:RolePolicyVM}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ComponentPolicyVM}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                       Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm stuck on (and not sure if this is even possible) is how to add logic which can dynamically render the proper type of control based on ComponentPolicyVM.ValueType.

Try to set the `ItemTemplateSelector` property of the `TreeView` to a  custom `DataTemplateSelector` that returns a `DataTemplate` based on the value of the `ValueType` property of the `ComponentPolicyVM`, e.g.:

```
public class CustomTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is ComponentPolicyVM componentPolicyVM)
        {
            if (componentPolicyVM.ValueType == typeof(TypeA))
                return TemplateA;
            else if (componentPolicyVM.ValueType == typeof(TypeB))
                return TemplateB;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a `DataTemplate` to select based on Type, paired with a `ContentTemplateSelector`, so switch your template of the `ComponentPolicyVM` :

DataTemplate example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ComponentPolicyVM}">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding ValueType}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ComponentValueTypeTemplateSelector}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Example ComponentSelector:

```
    public class ComponentValueTypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
            if (!(item is ComponentPolicyVM cpVM))
                return null;

            if (cpVM.ValueType == typeOf(string))
                return element.FindResource("ValueTypeStringTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if(cpVM.ValueType == typeOf(bool))
                return element.FindResource("ValueTypeBoolTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if(cpVM.ValueType == typeOf(int))
                return element.FindResource("ValueTypeIntTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Then in some resource file you need to define the data templates for the things you need (`ValueTypeIntTemplate`, `ValueTypeStringTemplate` , `ValueTypeBoolTemplate`)
Your templates can be defined anywhere, just need to make sure the `container` can see them (i.e. import the resources) so the selector can find them.